# Why there is not an "the" put before "opnion"？

Tags: grammar, articles

> It is now nearly axiomatic that people will work for a range of employers in a variety of roles over their lifetimes, with a much more flexible schedule than in the past. **Opinion** is still divided over whether this change is a cause for concern or a chance for workers to be liberated from the rut of office life.

Why there is not an "**the**" put before "**opinion**"？

Comment: Why do you think there should be a "the" there? What does "the" indicate? What does no article indicate?

Comment: According to grammer book,there are many rules for how to use article.But actually, using the article is at will.

Comment: "Opinion" without the article here means "general opinion". "The opinion" would mean a specific opinion which has been spoken about previously, so it would not be correct to use "the" here.

Comment: I think the "Opinion" means two groups' views on specific fact.

Answer (score 2):

This is a non-count, non-determined noun, and so it has no determiner.

The word "opinion" can be both count or non-count.  Here it is non-count, and means some general views of the public.  "Opinion is divided" means different people have different points of view.

If you used "The opinion",  I would expect to know "which opinion" specifically was being talked about — A particular viewpoint.  But it wouldn't make sense to say "The opinion is divided", as that would mean "one specific point of view is more than one point of view.

It would be possible to rephrase with "Opinions are divided"  with very little change in meaning, except noting that each person has many opinions about different specific topics.

Comment: I think the "Opinion" in the original sentence is people's opinions on the fact that people will work for a range of employers in a variety of roles over their lifetimes. Their opinion is on specific fact.